# how to access this child element - attribute in php simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to access the 'url' attribute in the media:content element below.  I am pretty sure this gives me the media:content, but I can not seem to get the url (see what I tried below):

```
$theContent = $item->children('media', true)->content;
```

**xml**:

```
<item>
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="my url" />
</item>
```

I have **tried** variations:

```
 $theURL = $item->children('media', true)->content['url'];
```

and

```
$mediaItem=$item->children('media', true)->content;
$contentItem=$mediaItem->children('content', true);
$url = $contentItem['url'];
```

No luck.  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Complete working code with output:

```
<?php
$xml = '<item>
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="my url" />
</item>';

$theContent = @new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$attributes = $theContent->content->attributes();
echo $attributes['url'];  //outputs: my url
?>
```

References: [SimpleXML Attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: why not simply `$theUrl = (string)$theContent->content->attributes()->url` ?