# get url attribute of rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm looking for a way to get the value of the url attribute with the media:thumbnail tag of [this RSS feed](https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=XLLease).

I currently have this code:

```
//getNamespaces
$ns=$rss->getNamespaces(true);

foreach($rss->entry as $entry) {
    //set children of namespaces
    $yt=$entry->children($ns['yt']);
    $media=$entry->children($ns['media']);
}
```

But the media element/object for the tag I want is empty.

I have tried using [simplexml attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) without success.

Comment: The crucial detail here is that the attribute you are trying to select has no prefix, and therefore according to the XML spec *is not in any namespace*, as [discussed in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260452/simplexml-childrens-attributes-behaves-different-with-and-without-namespace?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can loop the children of `$media` and then get the `attributes()` from the thumbnail.

Maybe this setup can help you:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=XLLease";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

//getNamespaces
$ns=$rss->getNamespaces(true);

foreach($rss->entry as $entry) {
    //set children of namespaces
    $yt=$entry->children($ns['yt']);
    $media=$entry->children($ns['media']);
    foreach ($media as $value) {
        $url = $value->thumbnail->attributes()->url->__toString();
    }
}
```